# Why am I getting this error: undefined method `stats_by_day'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a Rails 4 app but am hitting this error. I'm sure it's something that is going to be very obvious to someone other than me.

Here's my helper file which is throwing this error in line 10:

```
module StatsHelper

def stats_chart_data
    @start = "january 1, 2013".to_date
    @start = @start - (@start.wday).days
    stats_by_day = Stat.total_grouped_by_day("january 1, 2013".to_date)    
    (@start..Date.today).step(7).map do |date| 
        {
            date: date,
            attendance: stats_by_day(date).first.try(:total_attendance) || 0  #error shows up here
        }
    end
end
end
```

The relevant model file is:

```
class Stat < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :campus

validates :attendance, presence: {message: "cannot be blank"}
validates :campus_id, presence: {message: "Please choose which campus"}
validates :date, presence: {message: "Please enter date"}
validates :time, presence: {message: "Please enter time"}

def self.total_grouped_by_day(start)
    stats = where(date: start.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now)
    stats = stats.group("date")
    stats = stats.select("date, sum(attendance) as total_attendance")
    stats.group_by { |o| o.date.to_date }
  end
end
```

I'm working through the RailsCasts on charting but can't figure this part out.

I am trying to create a graph that shows the combined attendance of church services at one campus. What am I missing here?

So it seems that the line:

```
    stats_by_day = Stat.total_grouped_by_day("january 1, 2013".to_date)
```

is returning nil.

I have tried entering this command in the console:

```
Stat.select("date(date), sum(attendance) as total_attendance")
```

And it also returns nil

```
Stat.first
```

returns

```
  Stat Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "stats".* FROM "stats" ORDER BY "stats"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  => #<Stat id: 1, attendance: 41, salvations: 0, visitors: 7, offering: #<BigDecimal:7fb85b20b618,'0.2187E4',9(36)>, created_at: "2013-07-17 05:33:28", updated_at: "2013-07-18 19:29:47", campus_id: 1, date: "2013-07-14", time: "2000-01-01 19:00:00">
```

So it looks like the issue is somewhere in how I am calling the select method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is it perhaps

```
stats_by_day[date].first.try(:total_attendance)
```

(brackets instead of parentheses)

(it would be easier if you specify which line you're getting the error)

Comment: After changing the parentheses to square brackets I get the following error: undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass

The error relates to line 10 in my helper

Comment: that means `Stat.total_grouped_by_day("january 1, 2013".to_date)` is returning nil.

Comment: I'm seeing that in the console but I can't figure out why.

Stat.select("date(date), sum(attendance) as total_attendance")

is returning nil in the console but I can't figure out why. There are records with date and attendance in the table.